# Unable to assign values with Object.entries

Tags: typescript

I am trying to apply a `reduce` to construct a new object of the same type as the input. It seems that Typescript does not allow to construct the same object through the `reduce` but I am unsure how I can get this working in Typescript.

The functionality is to filter out empty string inside an object. The assignment of `acc[key] = value;` seems not to work as Typescript does not know if the `value` is assignable to `acc[key]`  as acc can contain multiple types (`string | boolean | undefined`). Using only one type makes this work. The following error is shown when assigning the value:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)

The [following snippet](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.0.5&ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgG2ASzAiAVcEDOB5AIwCsIBjYKAXigG8AoKKAMwHsWB%20ALih2ACdkAOwDmAbgZQCAQz5dJbdFMHiAvuIBuMqJoRwI3eElToskfMTIVq9RqxbcA5MFzAHAGjpq6dUi0G8efmRyAFFBINwqKEIScgA6CHCBXAAKHT0ASigpHCgAbRCAD34pcgAeAGsIEBYmWEQUNExsc1jgN0CBEQA%20DsNGkxaYyzyqmrr%2042azYfIAXTm8uZ8-AL5cBqjeAVCk5Fw49YATOFIIFJTS0g7R6o70iDmsym7aCWQmFNBIWu0pXWglCBUAc2yEwgcUAAZFC-gC4kEALYpDJxdAiYAACygrwADFkbIxsqRSLcQHMog8JCoJOtgHA%20IJiaRVB0aCpsrlJk1TLhZsAMuIgA) presents the issue:

```
type MultipleTypesObject = {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: boolean;
};
var value: MultipleTypesObject = {
  foo: 'test',
};

const strictEntries = Object.entries(value) as [Extract<keyof MultipleTypesObject, string>, MultipleTypesObject[keyof MultipleTypesObject]][]
const result = strictEntries.reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  if(typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length > 0) {
    acc[key] = value
  }
  return acc;
}, {} as MultipleTypesObject);
```

I feel like I am missing some essential information on how Typescript works, but I am unsure where to look for this issue.

Comment: Not an answer to your problem/question, but a workaround. Replace the `.reduce()` with `Object.fromEntries(strictEntries.filter(/*...*/))` - [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&module=1&ts=4.0.5#code/C4TwDgpgBAsgrgG2ASzAiAVcEDOB5AIwCsIBjYKAXigG8AoKKAMwHsWB+ALih2ACdkAOwDmAbgZQCAQz5dJbdFMHiAvuIBuMqJoRwI3eElToskfMTIVq9RqxbcA5MFzAHAGjpq6dUi0G8efmRyAFFBINwqKEIScgA6CHCBXAAKHT0ASigpHCgAbRCAD34pcgAeAGsIEBYmWEQUNExsc1jgN0CBEQA+DsNGkxaYyzyqmrr+42azYfIAXTm8ufFffwo+XAao2eA4pj4WAFswiJwU3gFQpORcPeQkCD4UlLyAfQ70iDmsym6oUEgtW0Ul00Eo4KgACILkJhJCoAAyBHA0FxIKHFIZOLoETAAAWUD+AAYMhlREA)

Answer (score 0):

The type of the accumulator must be annotated, otherwise it'll be inferred as `{}` and there is no need of unsafe type casts.

```js
interface MultipleTypesObject {
  foo?: string
  bar?: boolean
}

const value: MultipleTypesObject = {
  foo: 'test',
}

const result = Object.entries(value).reduce(
  (acc: Partial<MultipleTypesObject>, [key, value]) =>
    typeof value === 'string' && value.trim().length > 0
      ? { ...acc, [key]: value }
      : acc,
  {},
)
```